# GNU Gettext class-based API and plural forms with ngettext()?

Tags: python, gettext

I use Pythons [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) module with its so called [Class-based API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-application).

I do "install" the current translation via calling `gettext.install()`. Does does install the function `_()` in Pythons builtin namespace. The consequence is I don't have to setup gettext in each of the modules of my application. It works everywhere.

```
translation = gettext.translation(
    domain=MY_DOMAIN,
    localedir=MY_LOCALE_DIR,
    languages=[language_code, ] if language_code else None,
    fallback=True
)
translation.install()
```

I can use `_()` everywhere without problems.

But it seems that `gettext.ngettext()` for plural forms do not work as expected. It do not translate my plural forms like this.

```
import gettext
translated = gettext.ngettext('singular %d', 'plural %d', val) % val
```

The reason is that this `ngettext()` do not know the installed translation using a specific domain and context.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.NullTranslations.install

Answer (score 0):

The solution is somehow hidden in the documentation. The relevant argument when calling `install()` is `names=`. But it isn't described in [`gettext.install()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.install) but in [`gettext.NullTranslations.install()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.NullTranslations.install).

Modify this line

```
translation.install()
```

into

```
translation.install(names=['ngettext'])
```

Now `ngettext()` is available everywhere because it is installed in the builtins namespace.

Comment: The documentation for `gettext.install` explicitly does refer to the other part for the `names` parameter…